# Is it possible to write common graphics code to render visualizations on different platforms (Windows 7 and above/Android/IOS/ Windows mobile)?

Tags: c#, android, c++, ios, cross-platform

We have a custom built data visualization control to draw charts. It was developed using win GDI APIs and the application is built using C++ COM/ATL.

Now we have a requirement to port this module to C# .NET (for maintainability).
The requirement is that the ported .NET control should work in Windows 7 and above (preferably Vista also). The straight forward approach is to start porting the code and replace the C win GDI APIs with .NET GDI+ APIs.

However one additional requirement is to investigate the possibility of reusing the newly written C# .NET code and deploy the same as apps in IOS/Android/Windows mobile (cross platform). I have come across Xamarin, but it looks like I cannot reuse the C# .NET code containing win GDI+ APIs directly.

Q1) Is it possible to reuse the ported GDI+ C# .NET code for developing mobile apps (may be using Xamarin)

Q2) If the answer for above is No, and we chose to start developing the control from scratch(in contrast to porting), What are the alternative approaches? i.e. what rendering libraries can we use?

Suggestions regarding existing visualization libraries which can be used in Xamarin, so that the developed app will work on all platforms are also welcome. The catch is the library needs to provide flexibility for us to add custom interactions to the visualizations.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone is going to point this out sooner or later, so it may as well be me: GDI+ is not part of .NET. It's a native C++ wrapper (and extension) around GDI. This is relevant, since both GDI and GDI+ are inherently Windows only.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is a C++ wrapper. Yes I understand it is a Windows only solution, That is why I wanted to know is there a cross platform alternative to GDI.

Comment: I don't know who and why downvoted this very good question (IMO). Also, moderators can close it as one "expecting opinions" and that's true - ther are many choices and this question cannot have single definitive answer. My personal recommendation will be to look at [Qt framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software))

Comment: @mvidelgauz Qt framework seems to be a good solution for cross platform UI development. However, currently Qt is available in C++ and we are looking only for C# .NET solutions. ActiveQt is also ruled out because we want to be completely disconnected with COM as well. Thanks for your inputs.